# how to use admob ad by google play service in android

Tags: android, admob

I want to add admob by google play service. My code in java is

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);
    AdView adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId("My_unit_id");

    layout.addView(adView,0);
    adView.loadAd(new com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

this code works correctly and showing the ad at top but problem is that ad push the layout down before loading the ad. I want "ad push the layout after loading the ad". Please someone help?? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seem have to check for a listener **AdView.setAdListener** that have a method `onAdLoaded`.

Docs : https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/intermediate#play-adlistener

Comment: i added this code adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
         @Override
         public void onAdLoaded() {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          super.onAdLoaded();
          layout.addView(adView,0);
         }
  });  after showing ad for some time then it force close and give error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first."

Answer (score 0):

First Change the Visibility of **Layout** to **Gone**

```
layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

then write the below code for **AdListner**

```
adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAdClosed() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        super.onAdClosed();
                    }


                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        super.onAdLoaded();
                        layout.addView(adView);
                        layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }


                    @Override
                    public void onAdOpened() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        super.onAdOpened();
                    }

                });
```